# Apache2: Disable web services and only use mod_proxy

Tags: apache2

Is there a way to disable the webserver functionality of the Apache2 webserver and only use mod_proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question statement itself is incorrect. HTTP proxy is a part of HTTP specification. The HTTP proxy server is a specific kind of HTTP server inherently. You can't remove "webserver" functionality from HTTP proxy server, it is uncertain what that could mean.

What you definitely can do is just set up Apache so that any query will result in proxying. For that, remove any modules and aliases (like `mod_status` and `mod_info`, which usually get mapped into some page in the URI space, like `/status`), and update default VirtualHost to proxy `/`, or set up `ProxyPass` in the server context and define no VirtualHosts.